# Inserting XML data in SQL database

Tags: sql, xml, insert, sql-server-2008-r2

How can i get my XML data into the right tables in my database? I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<reservering reserveringsnummer="1" status="aanvraag">
<park>Nationaal park Oosterschelde</park>
<accomodatie>Appartement</accomodatie>
<aantalBezoekers>2</aantalBezoekers>
<startdatum>2013-12-12</startdatum>
<einddatum>2013-12-20</einddatum>
<voorkeur>Rustige plaats</voorkeur>
<opties>
    <optie>arrangement</optie>
</opties>
<klant>
    <aanhef>De heer</aanhef>
    <naam>voornaam</naam>
    <adres>adres</adres>
    <postcode>postcode</postcode>
    <email>mailadres@mailadres.com</email>
    <rekeningnummer>012345678</rekeningnummer>
</klant>
</reservering>'

'SELECT
ReserveringNummer = Reservering.value('@reserveringsnummer', 'int'),
ReserveringStatus = Reservering.value('@status', 'varchar(50)'),
Park = Reservering.value('(park)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
Accomodatie = Reservering.value('(accomodatie)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
AantalBezoekers = Reservering.value('(aantalBezoekers)[1]', 'int'),
StartDatum = Reservering.value('(startdatum)[1]', 'date'),
EindDatum = Reservering.value('(einddatum)[1]', 'date'),
Voorkeur = Reservering.value('(voorkeur)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
Opties = Opties.value('(optie)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
Aanhef = Klant.value('(aanhef)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
KlantNaam = Klant.value('(naam)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
Adres = Klant.value('(adres)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
Postcode = Klant.value('(postcode)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
Email = Klant.value('(email)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
Rekeningnummer = Klant.value('(rekeningnummer)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
@XML.nodes('/reservering') AS ReserveringTable(Reservering),
@XML.nodes('/reservering/opties') AS OptiesTable(Opties),
@XML.nodes('/reservering/klant') AS KlantTable(Klant)

INSERT INTO dbo.PRODUCT(naam)
  VALUES (Opties)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ProductID;

INSERT INTO dbo.WONING(naam)
  VALUES (Accomodatie)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS WoningID;

INSERT dbo.KLANT(aanhef, naam, adres, postcode, emailadres, rekeningnummer)
  VALUES (Aanhef, KlantNaam, Adres, Postcode, Email, Rekeningnummer)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS KlantID;

INSERT INTO dbo.RESERVERING(reserveringsnummer, status, van_datum, tot_datum,       woning_id, product, voorkeur, prijs, klant, aantal_bezoekers)
   VALUES (ReserveringNummer, ReserveringStatus, StartDatum, EindDatum, WoningID, ProductID, Voorkeur, Prijs, KlantID, AantalBezoekers)
```

As you can see i'm also trying to get the product and woning id's into my RESERVERING table, is this the right way to do this? Right now the program is giving me an error: invalid column name 'columnname', where columnname is the value. It gives me the same error for all the values i've defined in my INSERT statement.

Comment: What kind of database have you use?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 and i'm working with the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem. For people who are interested in the solution:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<reservering reserveringsnummer="1" status="aanvraag">
<park>Nationaal park Oosterschelde</park>
<accomodatie>Appartement</accomodatie>
<aantalBezoekers>2</aantalBezoekers>
<startdatum>2013-12-12</startdatum>
<einddatum>2013-12-20</einddatum>
<voorkeur>Rustige plaats</voorkeur>
<opties>
    <optie>arrangement</optie>
</opties>
<klant>
    <aanhef>De heer</aanhef>
    <naam>name</naam>
    <adres>adres</adres>
    <postcode>postcode</postcode>
    <email>mail</email>
    <rekeningnummer>012345678</rekeningnummer>
</klant>
</reservering>'

INSERT INTO  [PRODUCT](
[naam])

SELECT
   Opties = Opties.value('(optie)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
@XML.nodes('/reservering/opties') AS OptiesTable(Opties)

DECLARE @ProductID AS int
SET @ProductID = @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO  [WONING](
[naam])

SELECT
   Accomodatie = Reservering.value('(accomodatie)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
   @XML.nodes('/reservering') AS ReserveringTable(Reservering),
   @XML.nodes('/reservering/opties') AS OptiesTable(Opties),
   @XML.nodes('/reservering/klant') AS KlantTable(Klant)

DECLARE @WoningID AS int
SET @WoningID = @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO  [KLANT](
[aanhef], [adres], [emailadres], [naam], [postcode], [rekeningnummer])

SELECT
   Aanhef = Klant.value('(aanhef)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
   Adres = Klant.value('(adres)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
   Email = Klant.value('(email)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
   KlantNaam = Klant.value('(naam)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
   Postcode = Klant.value('(postcode)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
   Rekeningnummer = Klant.value('(rekeningnummer)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
  @XML.nodes('/reservering') AS ReserveringTable(Reservering),
  @XML.nodes('/reservering/opties') AS OptiesTable(Opties),
  @XML.nodes('/reservering/klant') AS KlantTable(Klant)

 DECLARE @KlantID AS int
 SET @KlantID = @@IDENTITY

 INSERT INTO  [RESERVERING](
   [aantal_bezoekers], [product], [reserveringsnummer], [status], [van_datum],      
   [tot_datum], [voorkeur], [woning_id], [klant])

 SELECT
    AantalBezoekers = Reservering.value('(aantalBezoekers)[1]', 'int'),
    @ProductID,
    ReserveringNummer = Reservering.value('@reserveringsnummer', 'int'),
    ReserveringStatus = Reservering.value('@status', 'varchar(50)'),
    StartDatum = Reservering.value('(startdatum)[1]', 'date'),
    EindDatum = Reservering.value('(einddatum)[1]', 'date'),
    Voorkeur = Reservering.value('(voorkeur)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    @WoningID,
    @KlantID
 FROM
   @XML.nodes('/reservering') AS ReserveringTable(Reservering),
   @XML.nodes('/reservering/opties') AS OptiesTable(Opties),
   @XML.nodes('/reservering/klant') AS KlantTable(Klant)
```